# Silverlight MediaElement Cloud

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement, deepzoom

Doe anybody know where i can get a sample silvelight mediaelement cloud similar to mojaveexperiment.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer and source code example here [here](http://bigpicture.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=12146#ReleaseFiles)

and in code:instead of

```
    Uri collectionUri;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(App.Current.Host.Source, "/Collection/items.bin", out collectionUri))
            image.Source = collectionUri;
```

have

```
   Uri collectionUri;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(App.Current.Host.Source, "/Collection/items.bin", out collectionUri))
            msi.Source = new DeepZoomImageTileSource(collectionUri);
```

Found a thread that related to same question [here](http://silverlight.net/forums/p/56997/145373.aspx#145373)

Comment: @TStamper: The link that you sent is about reading data in the Azure cloud. I'm talking about building a MediaElement cloud similar to what is on the mojaveexperiment.com site. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MojaveExperiment used Vertigo BigPicture

The company site is [here](http://www.vertigo.com/deepzoom.aspx)

Comment: Hi Graeme,

Thanks for the response. I know it was created by vertigo by the source for BigPicture is not public yet. I'm wonderring if there's a sample app that i could look at that mimics the behaviour of BigPicture.

Thanks,
Keith